# What determines how many smash coins I get at the end of a match?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I've seen this number change between 50 - 70, and I have no idea what's getting me these coins. I've tried changing settings, tried modifying the amount of players, the CPU's levels, etc., and it seems the numbers are always random each time.

Is the number of coins I get after each match just randomized? Or is there some factor that effects it? What determines how many Smash Coins I get at the end of a match

Comment: Pretty sure it's based on the actions you take in the match, like how many moves you do with smash inputs or something. Not totally sure though.

Comment: @Toomai So I tested this out by getting a bunch of Level 1 AI and a player (me), a 2 minute match, and I just walked around. No special moves, nothing.  AI did barely anything, no special moves.  Just the once in a blue moon attack.  After Sudden Death, the amount of Coins I received was 41. But I repeated it, doing nothing, and instead I got 52 coins. So I really don't know if it's just random or if there's factors affecting it

Comment: Match duration is a major factor in stock matches, but I'm sure there's more to it.

Comment: I've been seing somewhere that it depends on how many time you move the circle pad, but I haven't tested it yet.<br> I'll edit later this rep for more relevant informations

Comment: @Brian Interesting you said that.  I tried this out. I set up a match of 4 CPU players, all at level 1, so they pretty much moved around and did nothing.  Then right after the match starts, I "quit" the match. And what do you know, I got 31 tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of circle pad movement affects the amount of coins you gain after a match.

Specifically, the circle pad has to go to its neutral position before moving it again for more coins, so you can't just rotate it around.  Source:  [Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/2gcoqq/coins_earned_per_match_is_based_on_analog_stick)

Answer (score 0):

I think the amount KOs and attacks and movement there are effect it. With the amiibo player glitch I used 6 tramed ganons vs a lvl 50 amiibo with 99 stock. 45 minutes and bam. 3500 gold.